# Dos consultas volley en una misma clase android?

Tags: android, json, sql, volley, singleton

Buenas tengo esta consulta a una url externa, los resultados realizan el set y get a un recycler. El tema es que necesito realizar dos consultas mas de este estilo. Como podría lograr realizar estas consultas en una misma clase? Gracias

```
private void CargarPreguntas() {
    String url="/app/consultarPartidas.php?CodUsua="+ CodUsua;
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectResquest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, this, this);
    VolleySingleton.getIntanciaVolley(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectResquest);
}

public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("ERROR",error.toString());

}

public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    jsonPartidas jsonPartidas = null;
    JSONArray json = response.optJSONArray("contrincantesPendientes");

    try {
        for(int i=1;i<json.length();i++) {
            jsonPartidas = new jsonPartidas();
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(i);


            jsonPartidas.setName(jsonObject.optString("contrincante"));
            jsonPartidas.setEstado(jsonObject.optString("estado"));
            jsonPartidas.setCodPart(jsonObject.optString("CodPart"));
            listaRetos.add(jsonPartidas);

        }


            retosPendientes adapter = new retosPendientes(listaRetos, getContext());
            RetosPendientes.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
            RetosPendientes.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Comment: dos consultas mas exactamente iguales ?

Comment: La estructura seria igual, pero la toma de datos seria a distintas Url

Comment: solo cambiaria la url ?

Comment: Disculpa por no especificar, cambiaría la url y los tipos de datos a tomar. Y estas consultas se tendrían que ejecutar a la misma vez

Comment: y si creas otro metodo con la url y los datos distintos a obtener y los ejecutas a los dos al mismo tiempo en el onCreate ? , por ejemplo cargarPreguntas(); cargarPreguntas2();

Comment: No sabría como realizarlo ya que tengo que cambiar los datos de una consulta exitosa en el try del onResponse.

Comment: entonces necesitarias que se ejecute uno y al terminar ese se ejecute el otro, es correcto ?

Comment: Exactamente, necesitaría los métodos individuales

Comment: Es imposible ejecutar varias consultas a la vez en `Volley`, a lo sumo puedes ejecutar una después de la otra. Si los datos que enviará cada consulta son diferentes **en cuanto a estructura de datos**, también deberas implementar métodos diferentes para manejar las respuestas. Si tienen la misma estructura podrás leerlos todos con el mismo método.